# If $I$ proper ideal of $R$, $S$ ring extension of $R$, and $u$ a unit in $S$, then $IR[u] \ne R[u]$ or $IR[u^{−1}] \ne R[u^{-1}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, extension-field

Let $R ⊆ S$ be an extension of rings, and let $u$ be a unit in $S$. 
Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ with $I \ne R$. Show that $IR[u] \ne R[u]$ or $IR[u^{−1}] \ne R[u^{-1}]$.

Here is what I try: I have already proved that $u^{-1}$ is integral over $R$ if and only if $u^{-1}∈R[u]$. I suppose both $IR[u]=R[u]$ and $IR[u^{−1}]=R[u^{-1}]$. I want to should $u^{-1}\in R[u]$, so that I can conclude that $R[u^{-1}] $ is integral over $R$, and so  $R[u^{-1}] $ is a finite generated $R$-module.
so that $IR[u^{−1}] = R[u^{-1}]=<x_1,...,x_n>$, and so $Ix_1+Ix_2+...+Ix_n=Rx_1+Rx_2+...+Rx_n$. Thus we have $I=R$ is a contradiction.

my problem is I cannot succeed to show $u^{-1}\in R[u]$ after many tries, help please, or do I have the wrong idea somehow? thanks a lot!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225404/if-i-is-a-proper-ideal-in-r-and-u-is-a-unit-in-the-ring-extension-of-r

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221419/commutative-algebra-integral-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ If not then $\,IR[u] = (1) = IR[u^{-1}]\ $ which yields equations

$$\begin{align} a_0 + a_1 u + \cdots + a_n u^n &= 1,\ \ a_i \in I\\
b_0 + b_1 u^{-1} +\cdots + b_m u^{-m} &= 1,\ \ b_i \in I\end{align}$$

By symmetry, wlog we assume $\,n\ge m\,$ and, further, that $\,n\,$ is minimal.

Scale the 2nd equation by $\,u^n\,$ then use it to eliminate $\,u^n,\,$ obtaining an equation of the same type with smaller $\,n,\,$ contradiction.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering! I am not quite sure how to get $IR[u]=IR[u^{-1}]$, could you explain a bit more? in particular, why would $IR[u]=1$?

Comment: @user138017 $IR[u] = R[u] = (1)\,$ means $\,1 \in IR[u]\,$ which yields the first equation. Similarly for the second.

Comment: thank you! may I ask what would the contradiction be? I am still not too sure. is that we can obtaining an equation for $1$ withe a smaller $n$? but the representation is not unique, so I think it should not be a problem if we have obtained a different equation for $1$, I think.

Comment: @use When you do the elimination you obtain an equation of the same type as the first but with smaller $\,n,\,$ contra hypothesis that $\,n\,$ was minimal. It is normal to scratch your head a few times on this because it differs a bit from common related  descents. As D'Alembert said: "Go forward, and faith will follow".

Comment: Thanks a lot. yeah, i will think about it more, and also the last sentense is a well saying. thanks for sharing.